# Pidgin and conference via Google Hangouts

Tags: pidgin, google-talk

I have a question about `Pidgin` and `Google Hangouts`.

Private chats work in `Pidgin`, all fine.
But how can I get an existing conference in `Pidgin` via `Hangouts`?

Comment: You can't as of now; Hangouts doesn't use XMPP which Pidgin uses communicating with Google Talk

Comment: Any news about this? There's already a third party client written in Python... https://github.com/tdryer/hangups

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good question, unfortunately it's not supported by Pidgin yet.  Pidgin uses the XMPP standard to talk to Google Hangouts, Google Chat, Google Talk, etc.  However, Google hangouts with multiple people (conference room) does not use XMPP.  Using the web interface or mobile app is probably your best option right now.

Comment: Is this still current?

Comment: @AlexandreNizoux, as far as I know this is still current and most likely won't change.  If I remember correctly, Google Chat used to support XMPP chat rooms, but when they moved to Google Hangouts they removed that functionality.  It's unlikely they will go back to their old method of doing group chats.

Comment: A Hangouts plugin is (currently, at least) one of Pidgin's 2015 Summer of Code projects: https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/SummerOfCode2015 .  No guarantee of any results, of course, but it does indicate there is an interest.

Comment: Thanks @tbenz9 and tecu for the information. I'll monitor that.

Answer (score 6):

A plugin is available for pidgin for Google hangouts called: Hangouts Plugin for libpurple
https://bitbucket.org/EionRobb/purple-hangouts/

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for instructions on recommending software on Super User.  You should avoid simply providing a link. Instead, provide a brief description of the software and **how** it will address the OP's question.